# Insert Android view at the top of the view hierarchy

Tags: java, android, view

I would like to know if it is possible to add a view to the top of the view hierarchy for my Android App. Currently, I have a class that receives information from an external service. I would like to display information received as a custom alert to the user. Is it possible to insert this custom view at the top of the global view hierarchy, so that it shows above all other views. I would prefer not to start a new activity, just add the view on top of what is currently being shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Accessing the root View is as easy as finding it.

In the Activity:

```
FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Since the root is a `FrameLayout`, you just have to add a `View` to it in order for it to be on top.  However, note that the Z-order will change if you add other Views after this one is added. In which case, you'll have to use `ViewGroup#bringChildToFront(View view)` to bring it back to the top.

**EDIT:**

It is also possible to get the root view from another View by using [View#getRootView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView()).  This is not always reliable as the View may not be attached to the hierarchy (in which case the View itself is the root).  Or it's parent may not be in the hierarchy (in which case the Parent itself will be the root).

Comment: What if I want to find the root view in a class that is not an activity?

Comment: @AlexWilson: I'm not sure what you mean.  Classes are Java constructs and they don't have Views.

Comment: Thats what I was wondering, so I cannot instantiate a view class and add it in the global view tree from a non view or non activity class?

Comment: @AlexWilson: The Activity window and View Hierarchy is controlled by the Activity. You can not add to the current View hierarchy without the Activity.  You can, however, create a new Window from a Service and add Views to it which is what Facebook Messenger does with chat heads.  This will not be contained inside your app though which is what you were asking.